# Is there a simple reference implementation of ECDSA algorithms?

Tags: development, ecdsa

I'm using Node.js's `elliptic` library to do some signing on my app, but there is some chance I'll migrate it to another language. That library is kinda big and not easy to port, so, I wonder, is there a reference, siple implementation of ECDSA algorithms (key generation, signing and recovery) anywhere?

Answer (score 2):

I wrote the Ruby ECDSA gem and I would say the code is pretty simple.  That was one of my main goals.

https://github.com/DavidEGrayson/ruby_ecdsa